# Return list of items in order of how many related items there are

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to return a list of items in order of how many related items there are.

Imagine the following classes. and imagine they all had DbSets... `context.A`..., `context.B`...

```
class A
{
    public ID { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get a list of `A` items in order of most related from `B`. The query might look like this:

```
IEnumerable<A> GetMostRelatedAs( int numberOfAsToReturn )
{
    return this.context.A.SelectMany( 
        a => a.ID, 
        ( whatever) => new
        {
            A = whatever,
            RelatedBCount = this.context.B.Where( b => b.A.ID == whatever.ID)
        }).OrderByDescending( x => x.RelatedBCount ).Take( numberOfAsToReturn  );
}
```

Where am I going wrong in my query?

Comment: _"Where am I going wrong?"_ - you perhaps missed [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), because it's not clear what you expect this to do, what it actually does and what you have tried to resolve those differences.

Comment: I have edited my OP. I hope this helps more.

Comment: You can't use `ABTuple` in your query because SQL doesnt understand it. Secondly you may want to call `ToList()` so you actually execute the query against the DB

Comment: Use the anonymous type over the class

Comment: I've edited my question and removed the tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to this:

> I am trying to get a list of A items in order of most related to from B.

`to from` makes this quite confusing, so on this basis I'm going to have a stab in the dark with this one:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> GetMostRelatedAs( int numberOfAsToReturn )
{
    var results = this.context.A
        .GroupJoin(
            this.context.B,
            a => a.ID,
            b => b.A.ID,
            (singleA, multipleBs) => new {
                    // this is the projection, so take here what you want
                    numberOfBs = multipleBs.Count(),
                    name = singleA.Name,
                    singleA.ViewCount
                }
            )
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ViewCount)
        .Take(numberOfAsToReturn)
        .ToList();

        // here you can use automapper to project to a type that you can use
        // So you could add the following method calls after the ToList()
        // .Project(this.mappingEngine)
        // .To<ClassThatRepresentsStructure>()

        // The reason you don't map before the ToList is that you are already doing a projection with that anonymous type.
    return results;
}
```

***Edit***

To address the comments:

```
IEnumerable<A> GetMostRelatedAs( int numberOfAsToReturn )
{
    var results = this.context.A
        .GroupJoin(
            this.context.B,
            a => a.ID,
            b => b.A.ID,
            (singleA, multipleBs) => new {
                    // this is the projection, so take here what you want
                    numberOfBs = multipleBs.Count(),
                    name = singleA.Name,
                    singleA.ViewCount,
                    singleA
                }
            )
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ViewCount)
        .Take(numberOfAsToReturn)
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => x.singleA);

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to cast the dynamic back into an A object? or just select the singleA on the query? If not then i'd best use the Tuple class I original declared to keep everything obvious for other developers.

Comment: I'm guessing I can't just do a foreach loop in the dynamic list returned because I won't be able to declare new A as it will no longer have the A ID from the database.

Comment: You project out what you want in that `new { }`, so you could say `originalA = singleA`

Comment: But it's not possible to return an IEnumerable<A>, I always have to return the dynamic object and then use that in my view instead right?

Comment: If you have SQL Profiler, look at the SQL generated from this, it may look dirty and performance maybe poor. So executing a stored proc could be better

Comment: It runs fast as hell! :D . I cannot believe how elegant the syntax is. As soon as you provided it here, it was so obvious. Thank you so much. Loving entity framework. I come from PHP where you just do joins and then you have completely effed up your original object structure because new properties have been glued onto it. This on the other hand is so tight!!!

Comment: P.S I didn't add or need the ToList part as I am doing that in the controller itself.

Comment: I would say you want to do `ToList` as soon as possible, rather than as late as possible.